# É viável utilizar MySQL com Entity Framework 6 e obter boa performance de CRUD?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, desempenho

É viável utilizar MySQL com Entity Framework 6 e obter boa performance  de CRUD?

Comment: Como não vale uma resposta tão pequena: sim, é.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Defina boa performance.

Se for uma performance aceitável, sim, é viável, isto é provado tendo uma quantidade enorme de pessoas que já fizeram isto.

Se é para ter o máximo da performance possível, então não é viável. Já começa pelo Entity Framework que é uma camada extra ao acesso ao banco de dados, que por um lado facilita certas operações, por outro realiza tais operações sem saber exatamente a melhor forma para obter a melhor performance. Também podemos dizer que uma parte da culpa pode ser o próprio MySQL. Se quer o máximo da performance, existem opções melhores. Claro que algumas cobrarão algum preço, mas você perguntou só sobre performance.

Esta é uma forma de dizer que a pergunta não é facilmente respondida a não ser com um enorme "depende".

Mas o que é mais importante é que só dá para saber sobre a viabilidade tendo parâmetros claros e testar com situações reais que vai enfrentar. Mas se uma informação genérica é suficiente para você, entenda que qualquer produto que exista no mercado e tenha usuários produz resultados, pelo menos aceitáveis.

Talvez não seja a resposta que você queira, mas não existem respostas mágicas e definitivas.

Eu prefiro não usar estas tecnologias por uma série de circunstâncias, entre elas que não dá a performance que eu gostaria. Só você pode responder se elas dão a performance que você gostaria.

Comment: Cigano, quando cito "Boa performance" estou querendo comparar com Sql Server, pois existem clientes que tem uma base de dados muito grande, e não querem investir em Banco de dados. Quando à tecnologia, estou usando WPF,C#,MVVM, e tenho obtido bons resultados. Vale ressaltar que em alguns casos uso client-server e em outros SOA.

Comment: A resposta continua a mesma.

Comment: @GEtulio, se você está buscando perfomance em um SGBD Gratuito para um Banco de dados grande, aconselho você dá uma olhada no PostgreSQL.